# Is there a way to convert a physics object to a static object in phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm attempting to have a player moved platform that becomes a static object when the player moved character lands on it (when collision is detected). This is so the platform wont move from underneath the character. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *Phaser 3* and the *Arcade Physics* engine, you could use the `setImmovable` method, from the `body` object, [here the link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Components.Immovable.html).

Here's a link to a demo on the official phaser homepage [link to demo](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/physics/arcade/sprite-vs-immovable), showing how it can/should be used.

Comment: thank you for the support :). this solved the problem of the platform being moved with the players gravity. All i had to do afterwards was set x and y velocity as 0.